# Prevent further executions until next schedule time in Spring

Tags: java, spring, scheduling

I am currently working with a Spring project that is set with a scheduled fixed rate of 30 seconds like this:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000)
public void doThings() {
     ...
     ...
     if(true) {
     // How to stop the method from executing the codes below 
     // until the next 30 seconds interval?
     }
     ...
     ...
}
```

The method is currently schedule for every 30 seconds.

It will run some code to determine if the conditional of the if statement is true.

If not true, the rest of the code is executed as well.

If true, the method is stopped until the method is again invoked automatically due to the scheduled interval of 30 seconds, and the method is again running the code from the beginning.

What should be correct line to be placed within the if statement?  Or is there a Spring specific way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: would adding return; be an option?

Comment: @xsx4u Thanks.  It might be, but I was hoping to see if there is a better way.  Since if I return null, some of the logs becomes a mess.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build state into your job.  Here is one way to do it.  When your 'true' statement occurs, set the job into PENDING mode.  Then on the next 30 second cycle, PENDING->READY.  Then reset back after running the code.

```
public class ScheduleTasks {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ScheduleTasks.class);

public enum JobState {
    NONE,
    PENDING,
    READY;
}

JobState jobState = JobState.NONE;
static int x = 0;

@Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000)
public void doThings() {

    if (jobState == JobState.PENDING)
        jobState = JobState.READY;

    // Here I am just simulating your 'true' statement every now and then
    x++;
    if (x % 3 == 0) {
        jobState = JobState.PENDING;
    }

    logger.info("jobState="+jobState);
    if (jobState == JobState.NONE || jobState == JobState.READY) {
        logger.info("Executing code");
        jobState = JobState.NONE;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Traditionally, the mantra for a Java method is "one entry, one exit". Having a `return;` to stop the rest of the code from executing breaks this convention, so I'd advise against it. Instead, you could do some simple logical analysis:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000)
public void doThings() {
  ...
  // Analysis for condition
  ...
  if (condition) {
     // Do code that only needs to be run if this condition is true
  } else {
    // Execute for when this is not true
  }
}
```

If you're looking to only execute code when `condition` isn't true, then just do this:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000)
public void doThings() {
  ...
  // Analysis for condition
  ...
  if (!condition) {
     // Do code that only needs to be run if this condition is not true
  }
}
```

Since the intention of your question isn't totally clear, I apologize ahead of time if this example is too simplified. Please add more information to clear up exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Note to whomever downvoted: I'd like to learn why. Is it that the logic is flawed? The paradigm? The example wasn't broad enough? Help me out so I can help out for another OP at some point. Thanks!